# Не компилируется директива @supports

Tags: html, css, sass, grunt

Работаю в Visual Studio Code.
В качестве препроцессора при вёрстке сайта использую SASS.
Для автоматизации всего процесса - Grunt
(конкретно для препроцессора grunt-contrib-sass)

в sass прописано следующее:

```
.news {
   background-color: #f8f5f2;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e5ddd5;

   @supports (clip-path: polygon(0 0)) or (-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0)) {
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 34px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 34px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      margin-top: -35px;
   }
 }
```

после компиляции в стилях нету директивы @supports.
пробовал тоже и в LESS, и в других редакторах - без изменений

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может дело в самом SASS? Какие-то ошибки при сборке в терминале есть?

Comment: да в том то и дело, что нет. всё чисто проходит

Comment: Вы написали невалидный css должно быть наоборот (вложить селектор нужно в support). Вложенность в supports как в media не работает.

Comment: на самом деле, вложенность тоже должна прекрасно работать:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJRgad?editors=1100#0

я пробовал и первый, и второй вариант